# Thread Creation

Tags: pthreads

Why do we use `pthread_exit(NULL)` method in `main()` method when creating threads?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void *message(void *arg){
    char *myMessage = (char*)arg;
    printf("%s\n", myMessage);
}

int main(void){

   pthread_t arr[2];
   char *messages[2] = {"Hello", " World"};

   if( pthread_create(&arr[0], NULL, message, &messages[0]) != 0 ){
       printf("Creating thread failed");
   }

   if( pthread_create(&arr[1], NULL, message, &messages[1]) != 0 ){
       printf("Creating thread failed");
   }

   pthread_exit(NULL); -> WHY
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is documented in [the `pthread_exit(3)` manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_exit.3.html#NOTES):

> To allow other threads to continue execution, the main thread should
>          terminate by calling `pthread_exit()` rather than [`exit(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exit.3.html).

Basically, when you start threads, the current execution “context” is also a thread. The new threads have a life-cycle which might not be related to the main thread’s; so you need to end your `main` function with `pthread_exit()`, otherwise you’ll end up calling `exit()` (that’s what happens after you return from `main`), and that will stop all the process’ threads.

At the end of `main`, you don’t care about providing a return value to any other thread, hence the use of `NULL` as argument to `pthread_exit()`.

Answer (score 1):

From `man pthread_exit`:

> To allow other threads to continue execution, the main thread should terminate by calling pthread_exit() rather than exit(3).

From that, I'd conclude that `exit()` (or simply returning from `main`) will terminate the process (and all other threads) immediately, while calling `pthread_exit()` will hold off on process termination until the other threads finish their work.